# how to get the questions from a facebook fanpage?

Tags: php, facebook, api

i am trying to get the questions from a facebook fan page.

if i do this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/questions?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

i get the questions from my facebook page. and to get them from my fan page i need to do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1234567/questions?access_token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

where `123456` is the id of my fanpage and `yyyyyyyy...` is the access_token form that fan page.

but for some reason it doesn't work. I get:

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request.",
  "type": "GraphMethodException"
}
}
```

what other request is there different than what i am trying?

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions API has only been enabled for getting a users or users friends questions not pages. Hopefully this will be coming soon